# Returning all rows with count(*), including count(*)=0

Tags: mysql

In a stored procedure, I create and populate a temporary table (tmpAllUsers) whose columns are user_id (int), first_name (varchar), and last_name (varchar). In the database, I have another table (Actions) that records each time a user completes a specific action. The columns of that table are user_id (int), action (int), and actionDate (datetime).

To show the number of actions that a user has completed within some time frame is easy:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, actionCount
FROM tmpAllUsers
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, count(*) as actionCount
    FROM Actions
    WHERE action = 1 and
        actionDate >= @sDate and actionDate < @eDate
    GROUP BY user_id ) x
ON tmpAllUsers.user_id = x.user_id;
```

The challenge is returning a table with all users, including  those for whom the actionCount = 0. The first approach I tried used a union, but in MySQL, a temporary table cannot be used twice in the same query. My second thought was to use an OUTER JOIN, but the same issue of not reusing a temporary  table arises.

Can you suggest an approach that would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood correctly, you want to include also the users that don't have actions that match the restriction of the inner query, in that case, you can use **LEFT JOIN** and when **actionCount** is **NULL**, replace with a **ZERO**, like this:

```
SELECT
    first_name,
    last_name,
    IFNULL(actionCount, 0)
FROM
    tmpAllUsers
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, count(*) AS actionCount
    FROM Actions
    WHERE action = 1 AND actionDate >= @sDate AND actionDate < @eDate
    GROUP BY user_id ) x ON tmpAllUsers.user_id = x.user_id;
```